# Holding down the option key isn't allowing me to see boot menu on iMac mid-2010

Tags: imac, screen, bootable-disk

I get an old iMac mid 2010 without hard drive and when I press "alt" on Windows keyboard (equivalent of "option" on Mac) nothing happens. Then the Apple logo appears with a charge bar and at 3/4 the screen turns black. I try to reset NVRAM and change USB key but I can't see the menu!

Comment: Tests: 1. make sure it's the left alt you press. 2. Try an Apple keyboard, sometimes Win keyboards simply "don't work" at boot. I have one here; if I need pre-login options I have to swap to a proper Apple keyboard.

Comment: A mobility lab keyboard is fine or I need to buy an official apple keyboard?

Comment: Apple keyboard is Apple keyboard but you can try as many others as you like.

Comment: If you mean one of these - https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/App-le-Mobility-Lab-ML311890-Apple-Wired-Keyboard-QWERTY-English-Layout/224246118866?hash=item34361c39d2:g:gFkAAOSwfVRfO~4V - then I'd guess it should work, as it appears to be specifically designed for Macs. If you're looking at 2nd hand on eBay, you can get real ones for $£€ 20.

Comment: And for untimely black screen ? Is it normal ?

Comment: Let's see where we get once you can access the boot menu. Of course, black screen is not normal - I assumed that's why you wanted to boot from a USB key. Also try booting from Recovery - Cmd/R - & see if you can get to First Aid.

Comment: Why do you need to do what you are trying to do? There is no internal drive. Is there an bootable external drive? You can also accomplish the same functionality provided by the Mac Startup Manager by using software. Also, if the drive is missing, then what is the status of the temperature sensor for the drive? Maybe, the Mac is reading the sensor and shutting down.

Comment: But is the black screen due to the hdd temperature sensors who's missing ?And for the keyboard I buy one . I will receive it soon